# 301 redirect ugly URLs to clean URLs

Tags: .htaccess

hello i got a problem here. I was searching for solution but no solution found on this...
So my htacess file

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

It chages my url to prety url like www.example.com/index.php?page=xxx to www.example.com/xxx
So it works, but the problem is than i can acces the same page from both of theese urls. so it is like the same content from different urls for google. How to make 301 redirects from old links to new?

Answer (score 0):

Right under the `RewriteEngine On` line, add this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /index\.php\?page=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%2?%3 [L,R=301]
```

This checks against the actual request (and not the request URI) for an `/index.php` and extracts the **page** parameter's value, then redirects the browser to the URI of the parameter's value (appending any remaining query string to it). This changes what's in the browser's URL address bar to the URL without the `/index.php`.

Comment: Hi,

that realy works, thanx. But if the page point to sub category, for example www.example.com/yyyy/xxx . yu code redirects only to www.example.com/xxx . is it posible to show parent category? because now the same page  from www.example.com/xxx and www.example.com/yyyy/xxx

Comment: @user2132032 you have to add the "yyyy" bit to both the condition and the rewrite rule's target. So add whatever "yyyy" is in front of `index\.php` and `%2?%3`

Comment: im a bit confused  for example url: http://www.example.com/commercial-flooring/vinyl/homogeneos-vinyl/  and when i click on http://www.example.com/index.php?page=homogeneos-vinyl i got redirected to http://www.example.com/homogeneos-vinyl there many categories so i do have all of them write to htaccess file?